# Navigation with xib in iOS app

Tags: objective-c, navigation, xib, xcode5, viewcontroller

Please, help to understand the navigation. I'm working with xibs. The scheme is: https://www.dropbox.com/s/o82fxpte0hmyxcq/Scheme_Simple.jpg .
Here's my code :

```
@implementation AppDelegate
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    FirstViewController *firstViewController = [[firstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"firstViewController" bundle:nil];
    UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:firstViewController];
    self.window.rootViewController = navigationController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}

@implementation FirstViewController
- (IBAction)button1Tapped:(id)sender {
    SecondViewController *secondViewController = [[SecondViewController alloc] init];
    secondViewController.title = @"View2";
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:secondViewController animated:YES];
}

@implementation SecondViewController
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    ThirdViewController *thirdViewController = [[ThirdViewController alloc] init];
    thirdViewController.title = @"View3";

    if (indexPath.row == 0) {    
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:thirdViewController animated:YES];
        [secondViewTableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    }
}
```

So, I have questions:

1. Where should I create the next view? In my code view has created in "previous" class: view2 created in FirstViewController, view3 created in SecondViewController etc. All new ViewControllers are inside the method that initiates the navigation, is it right way? I think it's wrong, but the navigation is working.
2. Problems with headers in the navigation bar. It turns out that the title of view2 is only displayed when moving from view1 to view2, but when going back from view3 to view2 – header disappears. I googled, tried to add `self.title = @"name"` to `viewDidLoad`, `initWithNibName`, `viewWillAppear` – none of this works.

Comment: To answer point 1. I would say it's correct.
Point 2. From the code you have pasted here it should work as expected. You are using the built in back button in the navigation controller?

Comment: Yes, I don't use custom navigation items or navigation bars. The rest of the code is by default and does nothing. Maybe the reason is that I should create navigation bar in interface builder, create outlet, property etc?

Comment: No you don't need to create it in interface builder if you don't want to. I really can't find anything wrong with what you posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I've solved the problem with disappearing title of navigation bar. The problem was in my custom back button: `self.navigationItem.title = @"";`
It was working and title "Back" from my back button disappeared but also title of navigation bar disappeared too. The right way to make back button untitled is:

```
UIBarButtonItem *backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:nil action:nil];
[self.navigationItem setBackBarButtonItem:backButton];
```